# How can I join an array into a string while preserving quotes?

Tags: go

I have a string: `{"isRegion":true, "tags":?}`

Where I want to join an array of strings in place of `?`, surrounded by quotes.

My current attempt doesn't quite work:

```
jsonStr := []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"isRegion":true, "tags":[%q]}, strings.Join(tags, `","`)))
```

The above gives the output:  `"tags":["prod\",\"stats"]`

I instead need the quotes to persist without escaping: `"tags":["prod","stats"]`

Comment: If you're trying to produce JSON, why not just use `encoding/json`? It's built for the purpose so you won't have to use weird workarounds for stuff like this.

Comment: I'm honestly really new to go, so I hadn't even considered that as an option :)

Comment: A quick web search for "golang json" would turn up some valuable information.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel..or the standard library.

Comment: not really an answer, but if you plan on receiving json and you will only need part of it, then take a look at this library (https://github.com/buger/jsonparser).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your tricky approach fixed:

```
tags := []string{"prod", "stats"}

jsonStr := []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"isRegion":true, "tags":["%s"]}`, 
    strings.Join(data, `", "`)))
```

The easy and correct way:

```
// This will be your JSON object
type Whatever struct {
    // Field appears in JSON as key "isRegion"
    IsRegion bool     `json:"isRegion"` 
    Tags     []string `json:"tags"`
}

tags := []string{"prod", "stats"}
w := Whatever{IsRegion: true, Tags: tags}

// here is where we encode the object
jsonStr, err := json.MarshalIndent(w, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    // Handle the error
}

fmt.Print(string(jsonStr))
```

You can either use json.MarshalIndent or json.Marshal to encode JSON, and json.UnMarshal to decode. Check more info about this at the [official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).

Comment: I appreciate the help instead of just pointing out the libraries to consider.